# Получение информации через API

Tags: python, json, api

Пытаюсь получить информацию о погоде в городе, используя API Gismeteo.
Данный код не работает. В чём проблема?

```
import requests
import json
city_name = input("Введите город:")
api_token = '56b30cb255.3443075'
api_url_base = 'https://api.gismeteo.net/v2/search/cities/?lang=ru&query='
headers = {
    'X-Gismeteo-Token': api_token,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
}

def get_info_about_city(api_url_base_value=api_url_base, requests_headers=None):
    if requests_headers is None:
        requests_headers = headers
    response = requests.get(api_url_base_value + city_name, headers=requests_headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        return None
print(get_info_about_city())
```

Получаю следующее:

```
{"meta":{"message":"Bad token. Check request header: 'X-Gismeteo-Token'","code":"404"},"response":{}}
```

Comment: Приложите полный текст ошибки к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

токен который указан в вашем коде взят из [документации](https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/). Скорее всего там он приведён в качестве примера.

сам токен можно запросить через b2b@gismeteo.ru, найдено [тут](https://www.gismeteo.ru/b2b/)

вы можете воспользоваться [OWM](https://openweathermap.org/), получить токен сможете в два клика

Answer (score 0):

OWM прикрыл лавочку для РФ в нынешних условиях. Требует ввести данные карты VISA, Mastercard, чтобы получить более менее расширенные данные, включая почасовой прогноз погоды

Comment: На 7.11.2023 это не так. Получил токен без данных карты.